# How to prove the convergence of the resulting multiple series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In an attempt to prove the convergence of this series
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}$$
where the floor function ⌊t⌋ - is operation of taking an integer part of a number, so $⌊\sqrt{1}⌋=1$, $⌊\sqrt{3}⌋=1$, $⌊\sqrt{10}⌋=3$

I was able to transform it into a multiple series:
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{9}} -...-\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{16}}=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + (\sum\limits_{n=1}^{8} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) + (-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{15} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{8} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) +...=-2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + 2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{8} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{15} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+... = -2(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{8}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{15}+...)$

So we get the following relation:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}=-2\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \sum_{m=1}^{n^2-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
How to prove the convergence of the resulting multiple series?

P.S. sorry for english, i used translator

Comment: You overcomplicate it. Do you know about the Dirichlet convergence test?

Comment: i do not understand how to use this test in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You started in a sensible way.  With a slight adjustment, you can say the following.

$\begin{array}{lcl}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}} &=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{9}} -\cdots-\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{16}} + \cdots \\
 &=& -\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \sum\limits_{n=4}^{8} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} -\sum\limits_{n=9}^{15} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \cdots\\ &=& \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k}\sum\limits_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}\frac1{\sqrt{n}} \end{array}$

and $\sum\limits_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ is slightly larger than $\int \limits_{k^2}^{(k+1)^2} \frac1{\sqrt{x}} \, dx =2$.

So you have an alternating series where all the terms are larger than $2$ in magnitude (it approximately starts $- 2.284457+ 2.086980- 2.042558 + \cdots$) rather than decreasing towards $0$, and so the partial sums cannot converge.